# Generate report attribute error - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I am creating a report, inside the report I have

.append which is giving errors. the initial `paragraph.append` works fine, its the _2/_3/_4 that give errors

Initially I only had `paragraph = section.add_paragraph()` but added `paragraph_2` and `paragraph_3` to try and remove the error, failed.

I also tried removing the `paragraph = section.add_paragraph()` what am I missing.

```
def generate_report(dataset):
    report = report_util.Report("Evaluation of Software License Utilization")

    section = report.add_section("Dataset Stats")
    paragraph = section.add_paragraph()
    paragraph_2 = section.add_paragraph()
    paragraph_3 = section.add_paragraph()

    # Paragraph #1
    paragraph.append(f"The dataset has {Total_Count} lines of data. ") 
    paragraph.append(f"{Vendor_Max_idx} has the largest number of licenses with {Vendor_Max_num} which equals {Vendor_Max_P}%. ")
   
    paragraph.append(f"{Vendor_Min_idx} has the smallest number of licenses with {Vendor_Min_num} which equals {Vendor_Min_P}%. ")

    paragraph_2 = section.add_paragraph
  
    # SECTION 1 
    # FIRST BAR GRAPH
    fig_1 = section.add_figure()
    fig_1.caption = "License counts by Vendor"
    fig_1 = px.bar(Vendor_GB,
                   x='ProductVendor',
                   y='ID',
                   labels={'ID': 'Number of Licenses', 
                           'ProductVendor':'Name of Vendor'},
                   title='License Count by Vendor',
                   barmode ='stack')
    fig_1.show()

    paragraph_2.append_cross_reference(fig_1)
    paragraph_2.append(f" shows the amount of licenses each vendor is utilizing.")

    # Create Table1
    tbl_1 = section.add_table()
    tbl_1.caption = "Figure 1 Dataset"

    tbl_1.set_header(["Product Vendor",
                      "Number of Licenses",
                      "Persentage of Total"])
    tbl_1.set_data(Vendor_GB1)  ###TO DO ...
        
    paragraph_2.append_cross_reference(tbl_1)
    paragraph_2.append(f" shows the numbers associated with the product vendors ")

    # SECTION 2
    # SECOND GRAPH
    section_2 = report.add_section("License Count by Environment Location")
    paragraph_3 = section_2.add_paragraph()

    # Figure 2
    fig_2 = section.add_figure()

    # Bar chart
    fig_2 = px.bar(Location_GB1,
                   x='SoftwareLocation',
                   y='ID',
                   labels={'ID': 'Number of Licenses', 
                           'SoftwareLocation':'Location of Software'},
                    title ='License Count by Location',
                    barmode ='stack')

    # plot
    fig_2.show()

    # paragraph_3.append_cross_reference(fig_2)
    paragraph_3.append(f" shows the number of licenses per environment location.")

    # Create Table2
    tbl_2 = section.add_table()
    tbl_2.caption = "Figure 2 Dataset"

    tbl_2.set_header(["Software Location", "Number of Licenses"])
    tbl_2.set_data(Vendor_GB2)

    # SECTION 3
    section_3 = report.add_section("License Count by Environment Location")
    paragraph_4 = section_3.add_paragraph()

    # Figure 3
    fig_3 = section.add_figure()

    # pie chart
    fig_3 = px.pie(df, 
             values = df['SoftwareType'].value_counts(), 
             names = df['SoftwareType'].unique().tolist(), 
             title='Software Licenses by Type')
    fig_3.show()

    paragraph_4.append_cross_reference(fig_3)
    paragraph_4.append(f" shows the number of licenses per environment location.")

    # Create Table3
    tbl_3 = section.add_table()
    tbl_3.caption = "Figure 3 Dataset"

    tbl_3.set_header(["Software Type","Count"])
    tbl_3.set_data(Location)
   
    return report
```

Comment: `paragraph_2 = section.add_paragraph` should be `paragraph_2 = section.add_paragraph()`.  Without the `()` you aren't calling the function and getting a list, you're just assigning the function itself to the value `paragraph_2`.

Comment: Well.. I feel silly. Thanks!